# What is 'composite pattern'?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, composite, object-oriented-analysis

Could anybody please explain and give a real-live example of **Composite Design Pattern**?

Comment: [boring mode on] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern [boring mode off]

Comment: Check [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), It has an example in **Java** language. Also check [this post](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternComposite.aspx), it is good with UML class diagram and participants, it is implemented in **C#** language. Hope that helps. **EDIT:** I've just found [this good-structured article](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite) which has some best practices also.

Answer (score 5):

The composite pattern can be used when a collection of objects should be treated the same way as one object of the same type. This is often used with tree-structured data. Below is an example where this pattern suits well:

```
public abstract class Shape {
    public abstract void Draw();
}

public class Line : Shape {
    public override void Draw() {
        // Draw line
    }
}

public class Polygon : Shape {

    private IList<Line> lines;

    public override void Draw() {
        foreach (Shape line in lines) {
            line.Draw();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the pattern makes it possible for the code dealing with drawing shapes to be unaware of how many lines are drawn.